# async/await throws NullReferenceException how can we diagnose where we messed it up?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

we have started using async/await in asp.net application, now we are getting the famous exception in our production

> An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/376/ROOT
>
> Process ID: 3796
>
> Exception: System.NullReferenceException
>
> Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean
>   setImpersonationContext)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean
>   setImpersonationContext)    at
>   System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback
>   callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.b__1(Object
>   s)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Is there any way we can get more information about the code/task that makes problem?

Second question: we tried to reproduce the exception locally in a simple test webform application

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LogMessageToFile("before_task");
        var t = Test();

        tasks.Add(t);
    }
    async Task Test()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           LogMessageToFile("inside_task");
           Thread.Sleep(1000);
       }
            );
        this.Title = "test";
        LogMessageToFile("after_task");

        //  throw new Exception("");
    }
```

but we never get the exception in our test page seems that the code after await in Test function is never called and the tasks state are WaitingForActivation, why we do not get exception in this code?

Comment: try catch block araound await?

Comment: `this.Title = "test";` can be null if the page have gone and you do not take care about... to wait before the page gone.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The legacy type (`LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext`) in your call stack indicates that your [`web.config` settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/) are incorrect. Set `targetFramework` to `4.5` or higher.

`async`/`await` cause undefined behavior on earlier versions of ASP.NET.

> why we do not get exception in this code?

Because you probably *updated* the broken application to 4.5+ (which turned on "quirks mode", rendering `await` unusable), but created a *new* test application for 4.5+ (which turns off "quirks mode", allowing `await` to work).

Comment: thank you Stephan that realy helped, I was double checking the web.config we had <compilation  targetFramework="4.5.1"/> in production  but not <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />

Comment: Regarding to the sample code in the question can we say,when we are using  old config to execute the code after await (this.Title = "test";   LogMessageToFile("after_task");) task wants to rejoin to the main context and raises exception(bcz it does not exist)but with new config the task will be abandoned without finishing and rejoining and code will not never get called?
which means we might have still kind of bug in our code  that we have not waited for a task to finish so code after that might never get called, with old config we would get an error but with new config we do not get error?

Comment: @Mojtaba: I see two problems with the example code. 1) Tasks should eventually be `await`ed, and 2) `Task.Run` is not appropriate for ASP.NET apps.

Comment: and if I get this error and don't see LegacyAspNetSynchonizationContext? :-(

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Then the problem is likely in your code, not in the runtime, and probably has nothing to do with `async`/`await`. If it's not clear where the problem is, create a minimal example that reproduces the problem and post the code in your own question.

Comment: @StephenCleary It’s definitely from not awaiting a task. Looking back I realize I wasn’t very specific in my last comment! I created a test MVC action, created a task that delayed for 5 seconds then threw an exception. I didn’t await the task then got this same stack trace except it didn’t mention ‘legacy’. But I’m seeing a null reference exception when I handle it - even though that’s not my actual exception. So feeling very stuck because I have this somewhere else in my codebase and I have no clue where :(

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: I'm confused. You say you don't await the task but are handling the exception? Please post your own question with a reproducible code example.

Comment: @StephenCleary I'm confused too :-) Thanks for your reply. I don't have time right now to create a new question, but here's a summary to ponder. My test exception source is raised from`public async Task DelayAndThrow() { await Task.Delay(5000); throw new ApplicationException("VERY BAD EXCEPTION"); }` with `Task t = DelayAndThrow()`. I'm using `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` to try to 'handle' this unhandled exception. Even if I unwrap the `AggregateException` there I only see a null exception. Problem is I have this same scenario *somewhere else* and have no clue how to find it.

Answer (score 2):

I think after return back from "await",
the http request process already finish,
HttpContext should null at that time.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/ThreadContext.cs,56
and then caused NullReferenceException.