# Why am I getting a NullReferenceException only on the LiveServer in this Async operation?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

This is an intermitted issue, when I tried to post this live.

```
protected void searchasync(string search, string usproengineer_id)
{
    Task a = Task.Run(() => searchuasync(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task b = Task.Run(() => searchcasync(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task c = Task.Run(() => searchpasync(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task.WaitAll(a, b, c);
}
```

Then each subsequent search section has:

```
protected async void searchuasync(string search, string usproengineer_id)
{
    Task<DataTable> taskAU = Task.Run(() => searchUinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskBU = Task.Run(() => searchUexpinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskCU = Task.Run(() => searchUcncinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskDU = Task.Run(() => searchUcncmetalinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskEU = Task.Run(() => searchUurethaneinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task.WaitAll(taskAU, taskBU, taskCU, taskDU, taskEU); //Wait till these parts are done
    ....
```

So this code has no problem on my local in the Debugger running.  Or on the Test-Server which is "Almost" the same as the live-server.  That is, I have no problem running the threaded searches.  But I did not anticipate receiving this error multiple times that I can't explain:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace:    at USAProEngHome.<searchcasync>d__1b.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

This does seem to be related to this [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119095/async-await-throws-nullreferenceexception-how-can-we-diagnose-where-we-messed-it) But not quite the same.  I have the webconfig targetframework set to 4.6 and no legacy set.  It is possible I have something misconfigured in my webconfig but don't know what it is.

Comment: What do the methods that are run in the second tasks do? can you post their code?

Comment: The shown code doesn't have any potential of a NullReferenceException. There must be somethign with the not included methods and/or the passed parameters.

Comment: It's not necessarily the cause of your problem but you should use `await Task.WhenAll()` instead of "Task.WaitAll()" which introduces unnecessary blocking code.

Comment: The exception seems to happen in searchcasync, but you haven't shown the source code for that one

Comment: Please show this code: `USAProEngHome.<searchcasync>d__1b.MoveNext()`

Comment: 'Searchcasync' looks pretty much the same as... Searchuasync (but the database calls are slightly different).  And sometimes the error comes back on a different one.
Next question: I use Take.WaitAll instead of TaskWhenAll because I do want it to Block before running the next set of instructions.  Next (What do the methods that run the second tasks do?---? They make DB calls and return DataTables hence Task<DataTable>

Comment: Folks I have made some changes, and the issue seems to have ceased.  The searchcsync/usync/psync functions used to do some UI functions now they also return DataTables to the parent. Which is smarter.  I will keep watch to see if the problem still appears. (just less than I can reproduce)

Comment: @Nineberry... Your idea was sound, but I actually removed task-waitall() in the searchasync and just used await to listen for the three datatables to complete.  In this case I sorta knew which one would most likely be the longest, so I put that first, but not in all cases.  So should give me the best performance.

Comment: @RufusL The d__1b.MoveNext() is actually a generated function from the compiler.   I will be watching today as the newest changes will be 'live-tested'.  I hate to do it this way, but  I couldn't reproduce the error any other way and it will only effect our internal group anyway.

Comment: If you changed code and the problem went away, post the answer or delete the question.

Comment: @tymtam I couldn't actually explain why the problem was happening on 'Release-mode' on that particular server (and not the other...).  However, it could be something to do with the more volatile nature of the UI inside of the 2nd in tasks.  I will post what I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my own answer to the question and what seemed to fix it (maybe someone could still point out ways to **improve the design speed**...):
Notice above I had '...' in Searchuasync (as I didn't show the rest of the code). Now, I had moved that code to its parent 'Searchasync'.
So now the SearchUasync looks like the following: (returning a Datatable.. Each of the 3 functions look like this, and they each have subsequent tasks that run asynchronously)

```
 protected async Task<DataTable> searchuasync(string search, string usproengineer_id)
{
    Task<DataTable> taskAU = Task.Run(() => searchUinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskBU = Task.Run(() => searchUexpinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskCU = Task.Run(() => searchUcncinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskDU = Task.Run(() => searchUcncmetalinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> taskEU = Task.Run(() => searchUurethaneinjection(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task.WaitAll(taskAU, taskBU, taskCU, taskDU, taskEU);
    //Unconfirmed query...
    DataTable dt6 = await taskAU;
    DataTable dt7 = await taskBU;
    DataTable dt8 = await taskCU;
    DataTable dt9 = await taskDU;
    DataTable dt10 = await taskEU;
    dt6.Merge(dt7, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
    dt6.Merge(dt8, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
    dt6.Merge(dt9, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
    dt6.Merge(dt10, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);

    return dt6;
}
```

Then in the parent looks like this: (notice I've commented out the original task.waitall command, and I'm just using an 'await' for each of the 3 parts. Thinking the 'await c' is the most expensive.  By the time it gets to 'await a' or 'b' they should be done.  But maybe not in every case.

```
protected async void searchasync(string search, string usproengineer_id)
{
    Task<DataTable> c = Task.Run(() => searchpasync(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> b = Task.Run(() => searchcasync(search, usproengineer_id));
    Task<DataTable> a = Task.Run(() => searchuasync(search, usproengineer_id));
    //Task.WaitAll(a, b, c);

    DataTable dt1 = await c;
    ((GridView)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView_MoldProjects")).DataSource = dt1;
    ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView_MoldProjects").DataBind();
    if (dt1.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        ((HtmlInputHidden)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("hidden_4")).Value = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        ((HtmlInputHidden)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("hidden_4")).Value = "0";
    }

    DataTable dt11 = await b;
    ((GridView)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView_ConfirmedQuotes")).DataSource = dt11;
    ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView_ConfirmedQuotes").DataBind();
    if (dt11.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        ((HtmlInputHidden)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("hidden_2")).Value = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        ((HtmlInputHidden)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("hidden_2")).Value = "0";
    }
    //end confirm3ed

    DataTable dt6 = await a;
    ((GridView)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView_UnconfirmedQuotes")).DataSource = dt6;
    ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("GridView_UnconfirmedQuotes").DataBind();
    if (dt6.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        ((HtmlInputHidden)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("hidden_1")).Value = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        ((HtmlInputHidden)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("hidden_1")).Value = "0";
    }
    //End Unconfirmed

}
```

I've seen no evidence of the 'nullreference' compiler generated Async error.  It's been live-tested this way for one-day.  With numerous hits.